# Grouping attributes in SSAS

Tags: ssas

I have an account dimension where the same account can have multiple account numbers. So I setup a durable key to group these accounts. So for example

Durablekey AccountNum

1          1

1          2

1          3

2          4

3          5

The durablekey has no business meaning. I would like to have an attribute in cube that displays the accountnum but would essentially have the durablekey as the key. So if I selected accountnum 2 it would pull all the information for everything with a durablekey of 1. If I simply set the accountnum as the name and durablekey as the key I get a duplicate error during processing as expected.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension

Answer (score 0):

Hi there is sample data http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/55330

You need to make Parent->Child Hierarchie, that Account key was normal integer key and other Accounts will have Parent Account key, which show to Parent Account. Parrent Account can have multiple other Accounts:

```
AccountKey | ParentAccount | Code
    1              -          102
    2              1          10255
    3              1          10266
    4              3          13444
    5              3          13555
```

There is a lot of examples in internet just type - SSAS Parent - Child :
http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/databases/microsoft-sql-server/9780735626201/creating-dimensions/creating_a_parent-child_dimension

Also you can use sample database and SSAS projects, there is everything done on working Cube...